# How we can fix php cli issue with centos and cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, centos7

I have installed `whm` on Centos 7, but when I try to use a `php` command from `ssh` I get an error.

`php-cli` is not installed. But I checked from easy apache4 and it is installed. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Run following command to activate cli mode

```
source /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/enable
source /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/enable
source /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/enable
```